# Drupal 7 - How to check if a particular field has a value - sql query?

Tags: sql, validation, drupal, field

I'm trying to write a PHP code to validate a form input in a field. If the field has already value the system must send an error message. If there is not a value or the value is the same like the input then the form can be submitted.
The edited code is:

```
/**
* Implement a function to get the ID and the title of the referenced node
* of type Reservation
* by the nodereference field called Period
* in the currently edited node from type Board
* Try to do this by the node_load() instead of the database query
* Is it the correct method to get the edited node's ID?
**/
function period_get_value() {
$thisnodeboard = $node->field_period_1[$node->language][0]['nid'];
$reservationrec = node_load(array('nid'=>$thisnodeboard));
return $reservationrec->title;
}
/**
* Implement the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter function to validate
* if the field Period has already value set
* and if there is such to check if it is the same as the input value
**/
function period_validate_form_slickgrid_editor_form_alter(&$form, $form_state){
/**
* The current value is the title of the referenced node
**/
$valcurr = period_get_value();
$valnew = $form_state['values']['field_period_1'];
if (isset($valcurr)&&($valcurr!=$valnew)){
    form_set_error('field_period_1', t('There is already value set for this field'));
  }
return $form;
}
```

But it still doesn't work - does not set any message and allow for changing the existing value in the field_period_1.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, writing a manual SQL query in D7 is an absolute last resort.

OK so you actually want to just prevent the user from updating a field after the node has been created.

You can do one of two things. If you only want to prevent edits from the node/edit form you could implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and then add your own validate or submit handler. You would then validate that the field has not changed and act accordingly.

If you wanted to prevent it happening from anywhere, Eg programmatically. You could implement hook_node_update() and check $node->is_new and $node->type to prevent changes to nodes that are not new.

Comment: Hi, I realize that SQL writing is a last resort, but I'he reached that point I'm afraid. I tried every module that offers field validation (or at almost every one) but none of them is useful for my task. I've tried Unique field also but it just sets uniqueness of field values as I have to set a field value just once and every next time when I try to change that value a message to appear and warn me that there is already data stored for this field. OK, it is sth like locking the field after its initial value setting. I hope I could explain my issues clear enough :) Can you help me?

Comment: To confirm. You want a field value to be unique across the entire content type?

Comment: No, it does't have to unique - a field value more likely has not being changeable after the node is created and the field populated once. At least the system must set warning message when the administrator is trying to change the fields value, and not allow submiting the form with the new field value.

Comment: Answer updated. Have a go at the code and post back if you have any issues.

Comment: Do I have to implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() in a custom module? I've read the documentaion but since never implement that function before don't know how to add a submit handler. Any clue where to start from? And thank you for the help and the time spent!

Comment: Yes create a module of your own, you will need a .info file and a .module file. Enable the module and create a function called yourmodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, $form_state). You can find the form id by inspecting the form and searching for form_id. Post back with the code if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm still in the middle of nowhere. I made a module of my own and implemented the hook, but still don't know how to validate if a field has an existing value stored. To clarify more: the field I want to validate is a node reference and there are 25 more such fields. Every particular field is supposed to get value in a different moment after the node's creation. So my logic is:

Comment: 1. first to get the ID of the node which field I'm validating, 2. then check in the database for present value of that field and 3. get back to the form to validate of the input is allowed. Is it the right logic?

Comment: Hi, I've posted the edited code above. Not sure if I'm on the right direction anyway.

Comment: I tried whatever I could but it seems that I cannot get a new input value in a field by hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() function. Also - Is this function appropriate to get the currently edited node NID: function period_get_value() {
$thisnodeboard = $node->field_period_1[$node->language][0]['nid'];
$reservationrec = node_load(array('nid'=>$thisnodeboard));
return $reservationrec->title;
}

Comment: have a look at entity_metadata_wrapper for working with references. And if you're altering an edit form you can usually get the nid using arg(1) if it's not in form or form state.

Comment: I've figured it out at last - hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() handled the task.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I had planned on getting back to you with some code but i've been snowed under.